# Disable ktlint rules with ktlint-gradle version 12.0.2

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, editorconfig

I upgraded the ktlint-gradle plugin to version 12.0.2 and now it does not respect the settings in my modules' build.gradle where I previously disabled some rules like that:

```
ktlint {
    ktlint.setDisabledRules(["package-name, max_line_length"])
}
```

I also tried using a .editorconfig file but this on does not allow all the options I need. Disabling max_line_lenth did work there but I dont have the option for package-name.

[image: Screenshot of IDE warning when trying to disable ktlint rule.]

In the projects build.gradle I have the ktlint-gradle dependency in the buildscript and for allprojects I apply the ktlint-gradle plugin.

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.4'
        classpath "org.jlleitschuh.gradle:ktlint-gradle:12.0.2" // https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle/releases  
        ...
  }
}

allprojects {
    ...
    apply plugin: "org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it, I used the wrong rule naming in the .editorconfig file, need to use the ktlint_standard_*rule-name* format.

https://pinterest.github.io/ktlint/latest/rules/standard/

for example:
ktlint_standard_discouraged-comment-location = disabled

The IDE (Android Studio) still does not recognize these properties then but while running ktlintcheck it evaluates the editorconfig file correctly.

thanks to [wakingrufus on github](https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle/discussions/728#discussioncomment-7775796) for answering this question.